# Symfony2 - Is there a way to hook into an event for user confirmation?

Tags: php, events, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FOS user bundle for symfony2 and want to run some custom code to log the event when a user confirms his registration at `/register/confirm/{token}`

However, there does not seem to be an event for when a user is confirmed, so I'd like to know the best way to hook into execution when a user account is confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

You can override [RegistrationController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php#L86) (see [doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md)) to add logging functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use the dev-master (2.0.*@dev), than you can use the new controller events in the FOSUserBundle. See the documentation at github for details: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md

Here is a little example for the confirm event. Don't forget to define the service as mentioned in the link above.

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Security\Listener;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(/** inject services you need **/)
    {
        // assign services to private fields
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM => 'onRegistrationConfirm',);
    }

    /**
     * GetResponseUserEvent gives you access to the user object
     **/
    public function onRegistrationConfirm(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```